# Finding Table data in p tag with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

So basically I'm using selenium to automate copying data in a table and opening it in a new tab and making a separate page for it. So each tr has a name of a cell and a picture to go with it. I want to copy the name of cell and the picture from the link and create a new page with it. Any help accessing the data in the p tag will be great! I can't seem to find the path to the table since it doesn't have a id and do not know how to access the p tag from the td.

[image]

I want to copy the cell information then paste the information into a new tab to create a new page. I don't know if selenium is the right tool for this.

[image]

Comment: Unless you're dealing with Dynamic javascript webpages then you might want to use [Beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) instead

Comment: I just updated my post. Would using Beautifulsoup be the better choice here?

Comment: Please refrain to post picture. It will make trouble if someone want to write a solution. Better to copy and paste html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate all rows of table and access cell name and image from each row with below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table-wrap']/table[1]")))
element.click()


for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr//td[@class='confluenceTd']/div[1]"):

          cell_name=row.find_element_by_xpath("./p[1]")
          print(cell_name.text)
          image= row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span//img")
```

Comment: Where are you getting element from? Is element suppose to be the webdriver.Chrome(path)? The code you provided has an error, do you know why?

Comment: Webdriver.chrime(path) is about to set up chrome instance while your question is about to iterate webtable so my answer is specific to that.

Comment: What is the error? All code is typed from mobile keypad so please ignore syntax error. You can check the approach

Comment: The error is this selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class='content-wrapper']/p[1]"}

Comment: The table is within a script. Would that change things?

Comment: Are you able to find table? If yes then it should not make difference. Please check only **img**, do you able to find it. Comment cell_text for debug.

Comment: Do you have multiple table, if yes then class name is unique? All rows has cell name and img tag?

Comment: Good to hear. So all cell not has cell name and img tag